# Answers that work and are mostly right vs later always right answers

Tags: up-votes, answers, discussion

Sometimes the optimization for the right answer picks up only the working answer rather than the more correct answer. And there is a distinction. Here's my example:

[Adding HTML entities using CSS content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content/1412764#1412764)

At first (years ago) a ~10 vs 1 vote difference is attributed to my total lateness in replying (even in ever running into this issue). So I understand why the asker had picked that answer. But it's been on the site for a couple of years, and the answer that works for the question but doesn't always work for the general titled issue keeps getting votes as being both right and the best answer; maybe because it was chosen as the answer and works. I know my answer that points out where this working answer could go wrong is appreciated by some, since it's gotten some votes slowly, but mostly it's never going to catch up given the current ~70 vs 5 vote difference.

Do you think this is a problem for keeping answers current and correct on the site?

Note, before picking this as an example for my question I edited my answer a little to not start out referencing the other answer. You can look at the edits and muse over whether the wording led to this rather than the timing and the it-works nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I would say simply update the answer to make it always right.  In your example, you didn't even give a "different" answer as much as you gave an updated version of the existing answer that accounted for edge cases.  Back when you posted your update that was really your only recourse other than posting a comment on the original answer, however now with suggested edits everyone should be able to edit any answer that is only "mostly right" and make it more complete.

Comment: I think back at that point I wasn't allowed to edit other people's answers. And I only just remembered that this existed. There must be other questions like it out there.

Comment: @dlamblin very possible, considering the post's age.  Just makes me glad we have the suggested edits feature now! :)

Comment: You're right; that probably fixes the problem for the future then.